# How to configure Lenovo's ActivePen buttons in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: lenovo, configuration, touchscreen, stylus, krita

i have a Lenovo Yoga 520 and the stylus pen Lenovo Active Pen for the notebook's touchscreen. Everything is working fine, but i can't configure the stylus in Krita, nor in the confs. I can't seem to be able to install Lenovo's drivers to configure it. Does anyone know how to configure the device's buttons ?